# Raw socket SYN vs. packet socket SYN

Tags: c++, linux, tcp

I've made a sample that triggers my problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>

#include <iostream>

enum {
    IP_ERR
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        int fd;
        sockaddr_ll device;
        // tcp and ip syn data
        unsigned char ipTcp[] = {0x45, 0x00, 0x00, 0x28, 0x23, 0xc6, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x06, 0x59, 0x08, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
                        0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0f, 0xa1, 0x0b, 0xb8, 0x6b, 0x8b, 0x45, 0x67, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                        0x50, 0x02, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x3a, 0xea, 0x00, 0x00};

    // if any argument, send syn frame using packet socket
    // otherwise, send using raw socket
        bool asPacket = argc > 1;

        if (asPacket) {
            // send as packet
            fd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_IP));
            if (fd == -1) {
                throw IP_ERR;
            }

            memset(&device, 0, sizeof(device));
            if (!(device.sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex("lo"))) {
                throw IP_ERR;
            }
            device.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
            device.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_IP);

            std::cout << sendto(fd, ipTcp, 40, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &device, sizeof(device)) << std::endl;

        } else {

            // send as raw socket
            fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
            if (fd == -1) {
                throw IP_ERR;
            }

            sockaddr_in sin;
            memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
            sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
            sin.sin_port = htons(3000);
            sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(0x7f000001);
            std::cout << sendto(fd, ipTcp, 40, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin)) << std::endl;

        }
}
```

If you compile this on Linux and run using sudo, it will send a SYN from 127.0.0.1 on port 4001 to 127.0.0.1 to port 3000. This works and is shown in Wireshark and the Linux kernel will automatically send RST from port 3000 since we have no server there.

However, if you pass an argument to this program, it will send the exact same SYN but using a packet socket instead of a raw socket and this will show up in Wireshark as well, with identical content (TCP/IP). Problem is, the kernel does not respond with RST and I cannot get this SYN to trigger any SYN-ACK from servers. It seems what I send on packet sockets does not properly reach the target, even though I'm using interface "lo" which is my loopback interface on my machine.

Why is this? Shouldn't the packet socket also trigger the same RST response? I cannot get it (the packet socket) to trigger any kind of reaction even though it shows up as identical in Wireshark.

Comment: Maybe it's an optimization for the loopback interface. unix.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask this, if you're pretty sure your code is correct.

Comment: What happens if you send to a remote machine instead of the local machine?

Comment: What I posted here is just a boiled down sample, my full code is able to remotely connect and download the front-page of Google.com using packet sockets, I only have this problem for localhost (I want to use packet sockets since they are low level, but I also want to develop on localhost).

Comment: The problem in the question is when there's nothing listening on the port. Do you get a proper RST when you try to connect to an unused port on Google? If so, then it sounds like some kind of shortcut that Linux does for loopback.

Comment: Well the whole RST thing is really just a symptom (and to complicate things even more, Google does not send RST, but they don't send that even if I connect via netcat so it is by design on their end).

Never mind the RST thing, the problem is more like "packet sockets doesn't trigger any action on localhost but they do work remotely".

Comment: So it also doesn't work when you try to connect to a port with a server?

Comment: No, that's the problem: it works fully on localhost when I send using raw sockets (I get RST if no server is listening, and I get SYN, ACK if there is a server listening). With packet sockets, it works fully remotely (Google tested) but localhost is completely dead (I get absolutely no response, no RST, no SYN-ACK, nothing). This is strange since I explicitly send on "lo" interface, so Linux should loop it back one would think.

Comment: I haven't read through it, but maybe this page will be useful: http://yusufonlinux.blogspot.com/2010/11/data-link-access-and-zero-copy.html

Comment: I'm sorry but now you're just referring to Google links, I have read that article and it doesn't cover this issue (that article is about performance). I have a very specific problem. Maybe I should contact the Linux kernel mailing list or something.